# How to compile a Build Activity in such a way that it will work with TFS 2010, TFS 2012 and TFS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, workflow-foundation-4

The custom build activity depends on the following TFS assemblies:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll
```

The goal is to compile it in such a way that it will work on TFS 2010, TFS 2012 and TFS 2013 without having to manually specify binding redirections for all the possible Build Agent machines where the activity might be invoked.

Supplying a configuration file along with the activity and creating an application domain that uses the binding redirections specified in that configuration file seems like an option, but this ultimately would not work, since the "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildActivity" attribute that the activity must be decorated with* would be read by the calling code before the code in the custom activity's assembly is executed - and if the version of the TFS assembly that that attribute came from does not match the version of the TFS assembly loaded in memory, the activity is as good as if it weren't decorated with that attribute at all.

(* I have confirmed that if a custom activity is not decorated with the BuildActivity attribute, the custom activity's type cannot be created and the build fails.)

Removing all references to TFS activities and loading TFS-related types using reflection also seems like another option, but would fail for the same reason, since obviously the BuildActivity attribute cannot be reflectively applied to the class before the code inside the class itself is called by external code.

Since the few TFS types and methods the activity depends on exist in the TFS 2010, TFS 2012 and TFS 2013 assemblies and since the activity is compiled against .NET 4.0, the only reasonable workaround I can think of is to create 3 separate builds: one compiled against the TFS/VS 2010 (10.0.0.0) assemblies, one compiled against the TFS/VS 2012 (11.0.0.0) assemblies, and one compiled against the TFS/VS 2013 (12.0.0.0) assemblies.

(And of course, while I have the TFS2010/TFS2012/TFS2013 versions of the above assemblies on my development machine, the assumption is that the Build Agents will have only the version of those assemblies that comes with its version of TFS.)

The other workaround seems to be to specify binding redirections for all the Build Agent machines, but with a rather large number of Build Agent machines this is not feasible.

Is there an actual solution to this problem or am I stuck having to create 3 builds?

Answer (score 0):

if you go down the route of having 3 assemblies, technically you could create 3 BuildProcessAssemblies folders and add the

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll

libraries to each folder, then point each particular controller to the relevant folder.